# Pandas ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). when using map and apply

Tags: python, pandas

Here's a mock DataFrame. I need to fill values in `col1` from `json_col`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0, np.nan, 0, 0],
                   'json_col': [{'Id': 60,
                              'Date': '20210908',
                              'value': {'Id': 60,
                                        'Code': 6037}
                              },

                              {'Id': 61,
                                'Date': '20210908',
                                'value': {'Id': 60,
                                          'Code': 6038}
                               },

                               np.nan,

                               {'Id': 63,
                                 'Date': '20210908',
                                 'value': {'Id': 60,
                                           'Code': np.nan}
                               }]
             })
```

The task: I need to replace `0s` in `'col1` from `dict` object in `json_col`.

```
df['col1'] = df[df['col1'] == 0].apply( lambda x : df['json_col'].str['value'].str['Code'])
```

Note, when `df['json_col'].str['value'].str['Code']` returns `NaN`, we'd like to set `df['col1']` to `NaN`.

Comment: The `df['col1'].fillna(df['json_col'].str['value'].str['Code'], inplace=True)` that you removed worked fine for me. I'm unsure what you're asking, this provided code does not produce the error in the title for me. `df['json_col'].str['value'].str['Code']` is the entire Series which is going to give not the value you're looking for. What is the expected output for this?

Comment: @HenryEcker `.fillna` isn't the issue. I updated the question with `the task` which is what I am hoping for. hopefully, it clear now.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try with [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) instead of [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to create a Series based on where values are `0`:

```
import numpy as np


df['col1'] = np.where(
    df['col1'].eq(0),
    df['json_col'].str['value'].str['Code'],
    df['col1']
)
```

`df`:

```
     col1                                           json_col
0  6037.0  {'Id': 60, 'Date': '20210908', 'value': {'Id':...
1     NaN  {'Id': 61, 'Date': '20210908', 'value': {'Id':...  # (unchanged)
2     NaN                                                NaN  # Nothing to access
3  6040.0  {'Id': 63, 'Date': '20210908', 'value': {'Id':...
```

---

[`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) on rows is also an option:

```
df['col1'] = df.apply(
    lambda r: r['json_col']['value']['Code']
    if r['col1'] == 0 and r['json_col'] is not np.NaN
    else r['col1'],
    axis=1
)
```

`df`:

```
     col1                                           json_col
0  6037.0  {'Id': 60, 'Date': '20210908', 'value': {'Id':...
1     NaN  {'Id': 61, 'Date': '20210908', 'value': {'Id':...
2     0.0                                                NaN
3  6040.0  {'Id': 63, 'Date': '20210908', 'value': {'Id':...
```

Comment: Thx, curious if there is a solution using `.apply`.

Comment: Yes `apply` also works, included this option as well. You can modify as needed if wanting NaN instead of leaving 0s for NaN rows in json_col.

Comment: `.apply` works. However, with the data that I am working with, I am still getting that error. I made a edit to question, `df['json_col'].str['value'].str['Code']` may return 'NaNs'. How do we handle that?

Comment: Any thoughts on why we might be seeing `ValueError: The truth value of the series is ambiguous` in this case?

Comment: You haven't specified what you _want_ to happen in the case of NaN values. Additionally, I don't get any error with `map` as stated above, I simply get a string representation of the entire column in the cell.

Comment: The `np.where` option provides the behaviour you're looking for. The apply also sets `col1` to NaN when `Code` is NaN.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237149/discussion-between-kms-and-henry-ecker).